# Here is a Question about WPF Window Control

Tags: wpf, controls, window

ı'am opening a new window in a another window ,but when window1.show()' method is called,
window1 is down in the taskbar with caller window and they is grouping in that task bar,
I click the window1 but not showed the screen,is is still in the task bar...

Why might something like that  ?

Comment: it is Windows 7 feature, I doubt you should do anything with it from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you specify in Windows 7 that you do not wish to regroup the windows under the same icon, it is not possible per say. The only way I can think of would be to create a new application with that windows instead of opening the window itself., but that would be far fecthed.

Why do you need this ?

Comment: I want to count down number in a new window control so ı have a window but is not  showed